# Angular.js dependency injection in global function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, cordova-3

I am writing a cordova application with angular.js. When I use the PushPlugin to send push notifications to the user. I have register the user phone like this:

```
var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
    pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, { "senderID": [gmc_project_number], "ecb": "app.onNotificationGCM" });
```

The last parameter that I pass is `app.onNotificationGCM` this is a function that is called when I receive a notification.

This is the implementation of that function:

```
 app.onNotificationGCM = function (e) {
    switch (e.event) {
        case 'registered':
            if (e.regid.length > 0) {
                console.log("Regid " + e.regid);
                alert('registration id = ' + e.regid);
            }
            break;

        case 'message':
            // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
            alert('message = ' + e.message + ' msgcnt = ' + e.msgcnt);
            break;

        case 'error':
            alert('GCM error = ' + e.msg);
            break;

        default:
            alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
            break;
    }
};
```

I have to add it in a global variable (in this case the angular.module), in order for it to be accessible when the response is returned.

This is the explanation that I got from https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/309

> Because the Android JAVA code calls a function (I saw it in the
>   LogCat) called sendJavascript() this function contain a string that
>   contain the function onNotificationGCM(Json) that is called in the
>   document so if you load the function in the "onDeviceReady" it will be
>   avalaible only when the device is ready and not always like is
>   supposed to be (the registrration takes a few seconds to come back)

As it is now it works just fine. The problem is that I want to call a factory and make an http call from it inside `onNotificationGCM`. Currently I don't know how to inject the factory.
I tried assigning the `onNotificationGCM` function to `$rootScope` but it was not accessible on the response.

Is there a way to inject a factory inside this global function?
Is there another way to implement this, perhaps inside `app.config()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have an Angular `$injector` ([ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector)) for your application, you can easily call a function with dependency injection:

```
$injector.invoke(["$http", myfunction]);
```

You could, for instance, wrap the entire function as:

```
app.onNotificationGCM = function (e) {
    $injector.invoke(["$http", function($http) {
        // your code here... it will be dependency injected by Angular
    }]);
};
```

You will most definitely want to call `$apply()` - `$http` calls will not run before, so actually the code should be:

```
app.onNotificationGCM = function (e) {
    $injector.invoke(["$http", "$rootScope", function($http, $rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
            // your code here... it will be dependency injected by Angular
            // ... AND called properly in a digest cycle
        });
    }]);
};
```

That is only part one. Now the question is how do you get hold of the proper `$injector` for your application?

If you bootstrap manually, then `angular.bootstrap` ([ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap)) returns the injector. Just keep it in a (global?) var.

You probably use `ng-app`. Then you will have to identify the element that contains `ng-app` somehow and call `angular.element.injector` ([ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) - look for "jQuery/jqLite Extras"). E.g., if `ng-app` is in the `<body>`:

```
// in code OUTSIDE Angular
var $injector = angular.element(document.body).injector();
```

Comment: Well sadly I don't use jQuery/jqLite in my application, so I can't use the `injector()` function. I'll try to find another way and if nothing works I'll start using jqLite.

Comment: No, this function is part of the internal implementation of the jQuery API provided by Angular. **If you are using Angular, `angular.element.injector()` exists.**