# How to call a JavaScript function from an Angular controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

How can I call `showNotification()` JS function from an Angular controller? It is because I am using some plugin which contains code in that JS file only.

```
 authentication.controller('loginController', function($scope , $http ) {
 $http({
            method: 'POST',

            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
            data: $.param(($scope.loginData)),

        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config)
            {
                if(data.status == "success"){
            }   
            else
            {
                alert("invalid credentials");
                 showNotification(){
                        message: "This is Auto Close notification. Message will close after 2 seconds",
                        autoClose: true,
                        duration: 2
                    }  //THIS IS JS FUNCTION
            }
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                console.log("Login failed");
                 showNotification(){
                        message: "This is Auto Close notification. Message will close after 2 seconds",
                        autoClose: true,
                        duration: 2
                    }  //THIS IS JS FUNCTION
              }); 
 });
```

MY JS function in separate JS FILE

```
function showNotification(params){
  // Function Logic
}
```

Comment: Have you attached the external js file before angular files?

Comment: yes ofcourse. I have included that JS file that contains shownotification() function

Comment: apart I don't understand the call to your function ! you put the parameters in the body take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26628619/angular-js-dependency-injection-in-global-function

Answer (score 0):

Just include your plugin's javascript files, it should work.

To do it the right way, it would be best to wrap your plugin in some angularJS service or directive.

Comment: Please explain me. I have added my example but I am getting error

Answer (score 0):

Please see that demo http://plnkr.co/edit/unnI3qFBv2zah68MnTFj?p=preview

You just have to make sure that file with your js function is loaded before your file with controller

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.show = function() {

    showNotification("Hello from Angular")

  }
});
```

.... function in other js file:

```
function showNotification(message){

  alert(message)

}
```